# Buffered Image color change after rotation

Tags: java, image, web, bufferedimage

When i rotated a buffer image in java web application its color  change to red and this only happens in when save as JPEG format .If format is PNG it works

code..

```
public BufferedImage rotateImageByDegrees(BufferedImage img, double angle, int width, int height) {

        double rads = Math.toRadians(angle);
        double sin = Math.abs(Math.sin(rads)), cos = Math.abs(Math.cos(rads));
        int w = img.getWidth();
        int h = img.getHeight();
        int newWidth = (int) Math.floor(w * cos + h * sin);
        int newHeight = (int) Math.floor(h * cos + w * sin);

        BufferedImage rotated = new BufferedImage(newWidth, newHeight, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        Graphics2D g2d = rotated.createGraphics();
        AffineTransform at = new AffineTransform();
        at.translate((newWidth - w) / 2, (newHeight - h) / 2);

        int x = w / 2;
        int y = h / 2;

        at.rotate(rads, x, y);
        g2d.setTransform(at);
        g2d.drawImage(img, null, 0, 0);
        g2d.setColor(Color.RED);
        g2d.drawRect(0, 0, newWidth - 1, newHeight - 1);
        g2d.dispose();

        return rotated;
    }
```

image as jpg
[image: Rotated Image]

image as png
[image]

Comment: Strangely - you draw your background in red (`g2d.setColor(Color.RED); g2d.drawRect(0, 0, newWidth - 1, newHeight - 1)` - but your questions assumes that behaviour is not wanted...

Comment: Quick fix: Change your image type to `TYPE_INT_RGB` (i.e.: don't use alpha in JPEGs, it just confuses most software).